# React State Array of Objects returning value as [object object]

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to map over an array in State and display the object values for title, but I keep getting `[object object]`.

The below code only returns the title values when displayed as a console.log. I'm not sure what I'm missing, but any tips would be appreciated!

```
// State
const [cart, setCart] = useState({
wasteContents: []
});

// Set State
setAnswers(prevAnswers => {
            const wasteContents = prevAnswers.wasteContents;
            const alreadyExists =
        wasteContents.find(item => item.title === title) !== undefined;

            if (!alreadyExists) {
                wasteContents.push({
                    title,
                    quantity: 0,
                });
            }

            return {
                ...prevAnswers,
                wasteContents: wasteContents.map(item => {
                    if (item.title === title) {
                        return {
                            ...item,
                            quantity,
                        };
                    }

                    return item;
                }),
            };
        });

// Map
cart.wasteContents.map(items => {
return items.title; // [object object]
// return console.log(); // prints value of 'title'
});

// Data saved in state
State
:
{wasteContents: Array(3), wasteQuantity: "Singular …}
wasteQuantity
:
"Singular Item(s)"
wasteQuantityWeight
:
undefined

wasteContents
:
[{…}, {…}, {…}]


0
:
{quantity: 2, title: "Household Junk"}


1
:
{quantity: 1, title: "Furniture"}


2
:
{quantity: 1, title: "Appliances"}
```

Comment: Can you add console.log(items) before return and share what you have inside?

Comment: The console.log is returning `{title: 'Household Junk', quantity: 1}`.

Comment: Can you give an example of an object in the array?

Comment: This is not problematic.

Comment: [{title: 'Household Junk', quantity: 1}, {..}]

Answer (score 2):

Your function with your input works fine as expected

```js
let wasteContents = [{title: 'Household Junk', quantity: 1}, {title: '33Household Junk', quantity: 1}, {title: '22Household Junk', quantity: 1}]

const test = () => wasteContents.map(items => {
console.log(items)
return items.title;
});

test();
```

I see react tag in your component so I guess you are using this to render some components. You should update in this way

```js
{cart.wasteContents.map(items =>
      return ( <p>{items.title}</p> )
)}
```

Comment: This is still returning [object object]

Comment: Can you share codesandbox example with your code? It should work since that's just normal mapping function. I guess you have some other errors in your code @moody1208

Comment: I can't do a sandbox at the moment, but i've added the function that sets state. 

```

Answer (score 0):

So in the end I've got this working by using `return cart.wasteContents.map((item) => { return item.title; });`! The reason the previous answer didn't work was down to missing off the `return` for the actual map function!